# Show spinner on video end instead of play button

Tags: javascript, drupal, video.js

I have developed a video playlist for a Drupal site. My question is: Is it possible to show the spinner instead of the big play button on every video ending(through Javascript), until the page containing the next video of each list is loaded? The videojs version that's used is 2.0.2.

Comment: 2.0.2? The current version is 4.3

Comment: I'm aware. But the site is built from the ground on this version and cannot change